# Bootstrap - jquery php to load input fields of modal-window

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I would want to load a input fields of modal window using php. I have read that the best option is call with ajax. I do not know anything about ajax.

The idea is:

1) The user click in edit button.
2) Jquery launch on show modal window.
3) Query using php to get all of fields of the a record. (POST code value to use in WHERE)
4) Add this values in input fields of the modal window.

Code:

```
$('#edit').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {

            $.ajax({ 
                url: 'queryProduct.php?codigo=value',
                method: 'POST' 
            }).done(function(response){
                response = JSON.parse(response);



            });
```

The first step would be change codigo=value by codigo=variable. After that the second step would be recovery the query values of the script.php to assign in the modal-window, I do not know it.

Code php:

```
<?php   
        session_start();

        if(isset($_SESSION['username']) and $_SESSION['username'] <> ''){

                include("functions.php"); 
                include("tools.php"); 

                $conn = Conectarse("localhost", "5432", "dbname", "dbuser", "dbpass");  

                $codigo = $_POST['codigo'];


                $query = "SELECT pagina, edicion, descripcion_esp FROM produccion.ma_producto WHERE codigo={$codigo}"; 

                $result = pg_query($conn, $query);  

                if ($result == TRUE) {
                    echo json_encode($result);
                } else {
                    echo "Error query: " . $conn->error;
                }


        } else{
            ?><p>Session inactive</a></p>
<?php   
        }?>
```

Now How do it to get back the values of the query of the queryProduct.php?

[@Zakaria Acharki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4281779/zakaria-acharki) knows to get values using jquery but it would like better option to use ajax and launch a query.

Thanks masters!

Comment: missing a property name there @mplungjan

Comment: @Pamblam Not sure I follow you? I see `header('Location: produccio.php');` so it will be some kind of html content I take it

Comment: @mplungjan - actually i thought you meant to add the function as the `success` or `complete` setting property, i didn't realize you were passing it as a second parameter to `$.ajax()` ...i'm not familiar with that signature, if that is a valid signature it's [not documented](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: @Pamblam sorry you are correct. There are more things wrong since the php expexts a post. Your code uses the default GET so you may want to fix that. Here is how to post easily: `$.post("queryProduct.php", {"codigo":value },function(data){ $("#somecontainer").html(data);});`

Comment: yeah.. that signature isn't documented either. there are a maximum of two parameters and none of them are functions.

Comment: but good point on the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to catch the output of the AJAX call in jQuery. My favorite looks like this:

```
$.ajax({ 
    url: 'queryProduct.php',
    data: {codigo: "some value or variable here"}, // will be available on the server as $_POST['codigo']
    method: "POST" 
}).done(function(response){
    $("#myInput").val(response);
    $("#myModal").modal('show');
});
```

This will put whatever is outputted by the PHP script into the input and then open a modal.

Comment: Ok  @Pamblan but How do you get the values of the others fields of the query? I updated the sql query of php code. Example: How do you get the value of the pagina field from jquery?

Comment: I don't know because you didn't post the code for the `Conectarse` class or the `pg_query` function. If I don't know what those are I can't tell you how to use them to get the results.

Comment: Conectarse only connect to database, return conn. The is a function of php to query in postgres database, this function return values of the query: with this loop every rows, in this case only a row, `while ($row = pg_fetch_row($result)){`  to get values for example `$row[0]`.

Comment: if it returns the values from the database then you need to check `if($result !== false)` your current code implies that a successful call will return `true`.. if it does return the results then all you have to do it `echo json_encode($result);` and then in the AJAX, `response = JSON.parse(response);`

Comment: also someone made a good point in the comments, my example uses the GET method and your code uses the POST method, so you'll have to change one or the other..

Comment: I do not understand well. What do you mean that GET or POST method? I have used POST.

Comment: @ruzD Pamblam is using GET (default) - he needs to add `,method:"POST"`

Comment: I have updated my code with your advices. I do not know to POST the code value to php and I do not know to GET the values from php to jquery